# MYSQL Longblob vs local store for images

Tags: php, mysql

Need an advice from someone with experience on MYSQL and database servers. We are doing a project for users uploading photos to their website. I'm at the early stage of designing the database and wanted to know which way is better to store images out of these two options:

> 1. Storing all the images as binary data into a table as LONGBLOB
>      datatype. (This method is easier for us to handle and code the
>      website/applications)
> 2. Storing all the images as it is into a local folder and record the
>      file path into a table. (This method involves bit of more coding)

Now what I started to think is even though first one is easy will it make client database bigger and making decrease of server performance? I don't have the experience of working with such a huge database before and I would gladly appreciate anyone who came across this before. Testing with some data on my home PC doesn't help as we are creating this for thousands of users who upload images in daily basis. Thanks

Comment: Depends of the architecture.
Will this APP run on a single server or will be load balances between different servers?
Will the mySQL be one instance only?
Will you use CDN?
How do you estimate the image count uploaded? 100? 100000 ?
Will this images be read everytime from the database when accessed via web?

Comment: How many pictures and what size are we talking about? Using a directory, you have a lot of disc I/O, using a database, you have it partially or temporary in the memory, which is better I think if you don't do full-table scans.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found a good explanation here http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=64525